# Sum qunatities in the sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have this function

```
public function get_quantity($product_id,$event_start_date) {
     $qStr ="SELECT 
              order_items.quantity
             FROM
              order_items
             WHERE
              product_id = $product_id 
             AND
              (SELECT shows.event_end_date FROM
               shows
               INNER JOIN order_items ON
               shows.order_id = order_items.order_id
                WHERE
                order_items.product_id = $product_id
                 ) > $event_start_date";
               $query = $this->db->query($qStr);
              $result = $query->row_array();
              return (!empty($result) ? $result['quantity']:0 );
   }
```

Sub query is returning many results.so we have many quantities,  I have to sum the all qunatities.
Please help me out for the correct function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your subquery returns more than 1 row, your query shouldn't be working.

Comment: Don't join in the sub-query, relate to the outer order_items instead.

Comment: all the quantities product wise or overall quantites

Answer (score 0):

Use a `join` and `sum()` to get total product quantity from `order_items`

```
SELECT 
  SUM(i.quantity) total_quantity 
FROM
  order_items i 
  INNER JOIN shows s 
    ON s.order_id = i.order_id 
WHERE s.event_end_date > $event_start_date 
  AND i.product_id = $product_id
```

Comment: ssub query returning more than   1 row

Comment: @umair your comment is irrelevant to my answer because it has a **JOIN** not a subquery

Comment: have you looked at you code before submitting? How you can say it does not have a sub query?

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan Can you show me where it has a sub query its uses join for reference see [subqueries section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid If you query inside the query it's called sub query like you have in the query above.
`product_id = $product_id 
             AND
              (SELECT shows.event_end_dat`

Comment: @MusaddiqKhan i haven't suggest OP to use my query as a sub query ,its a complete query to his answer